# Compare inputted hex code to a pre-existing list?

Tags: python, colors, hex, rgb

I currently have Python code to compare RGB values to a pre-existing list of colors and find the closest match, but I'm working with someone else on this and realized that they've been color-picking hex codes from the palettes we're using rather than the RGB values (because I said that's what format I needed without realizing that my code didn't accommodate that).

I was wondering if anyone knows of a good way to compare hex codes to a pre-existing list of colors in Python (or, even better, in HTML/JavaScript, since I'm hoping to make this project accessible to a lot of people who don't have Python).

```
from math import sqrt

# these are just examples of colors, not all the ones that we're going to use
COLORS = (
    (181, 230, 99),
    (23, 186, 241),
    (99, 23, 153),
    (231, 99, 29),
)

def closest_color(rgb):
    r, g, b = rgb
    color_diffs = []
    for color in COLORS:
        cr, cg, cb = color
        color_diff = sqrt(abs(r - cr)**2 + abs(g - cg)**2 + abs(b - cb)**2)
        color_diffs.append((color_diff, color))
    return min(color_diffs)[1]

closest_color((12, 34, 156))
# => (99, 23, 153)
```

Comment: Could you clarify what the issue is with your code as it is?

Comment: You can find the minimum "distance" between two sets of color coordinates using Python's [`math.hypot()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot) function. Actually you don't really need the `sqrt()` of the distances squared because it could be used to do the comparison. There's nothing in your code about hex codes, by the way, so why is it in the title of your question?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I'm trying to compare hex codes rather than comparing RGB values - I'm not sure how to modify my code for that

Comment: The only practical why to compare them would be to convert the hex values to RGB components and doing some math.